# SQL Pivot and group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody help me with the following issue?
Here's the situation , i have the following table :

| signalName | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alarm | 10 | 2020-01-01 |
| Warning | 7 | 2020-01-01 |
| Check | 4 | 2020-01-01 |
| Alarm | 1 | 2020-01-02 |
| Warning | 4 | 2020-01-02 |
| Check | 3 | 2020-01-02 |

Each day 3 records get added to my table , to register values for each signal , what i'd like to do here
is to get the following table with a select statement:

| valueAlarm | valueWarning | valueCheck | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 | 4 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 2020-01-02 |

So that i'm able to group by date and have for each record the 3 types of values for each signal , i was looking into the pivot examples documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15
but can't get to have a working query.

Comment: So is your attempt so far? Why doesn't what you have work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am sharing two way of solving your problem:

**Schema:**

```
 create table mytable (signalName varchar(20),  value   int, date date)
 insert into mytable values('Alarm',    10, '2020-01-01');
 insert into mytable values('Warning',  7,  '2020-01-01');
 insert into mytable values('Check',    4,  '2020-01-01');
 insert into mytable values('Alarm',    1,  '2020-01-02');
 insert into mytable values('Warning',  4,  '2020-01-02');
 insert into mytable values('Check',    3,  '2020-01-02');
```

**Query with simple aggregation and group by:**

```
 select max(case when signalname='Alarm' then value end)ValueAlarm,
  max(case when signalname='Warning' then value end )ValueWarning,
   max(case when signalname='Check' then value end )ValueCheck,
   date
   from mytable
   group by date
```

**Output:**

| ValueAlarm | ValueWarning | ValueCheck | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 | 4 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 2020-01-02 |

**Query with pivot:**

```
 SELECT   
 Alarm ValueAlarm, Warning ValueWarning, [Check] ValueCheck,date
 FROM  
 (SELECT signalname,value,date
     FROM mytable) AS SourceTable  
 PIVOT  
 (  
 max(value)  
 FOR signalname IN ([Alarm], [Warning], [Check])  
 ) AS PivotTable;
```

**Output:**

| ValueAlarm | ValueWarning | ValueCheck | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 | 4 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 2020-01-02 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8120069279499d1ffbcb9c2ff56ad746)*

Answer (score 1):

the pivot syntax for your example should be something like this :

```
SELECT *
from(select * from table) src 
PIVOT (sum(value) FOR signalName in ([Alarm],[Warning],[Check]))  pvt
```

you can max() instead of sum() as well